# Suggest a Mac Notifications app with cloud sync to an accompanying iPhone app?

Tags: macos, ios, software-recommendation, data-synchronization, network

I'm looking for an app in which I can write down a quick message for myself on the Mac that can later pop up on my iPhone and remind me via a push notification.

I'm not looking for a full-featured task manager.  I know I could do this with iCal, but it's overkill for what I'm looking for. iCal is closer in nature to full featured task management apps than I'd like.

I know about two options that fit quite precisely what I'm after:

- http://www.NotifyMeCloud.com/
  This looks solid. And pretty. Maybe I'm expecting too much, but the fact that the last update to the app occurred June 23rd 2011 gives me pause. It's almost September. Then again, if the app works and is mature, that's not important. But that is rarely the case.
  The Mac App only has a single review in the Swiss App Store, and it's one star. User says the UI for entering new notifications is terrible. That it's so bad he's actually faster doing it on the iPhone, defeating the whole purpose of a Mac client. Can anyone tell me more on this? Or let me know what the reviews in the US look like? iPhone app reviews are also pretty mixed with an average of 3.5 stars out of 29 reviews.
- http://notificant.com/
  I'm not sure what's up here, but this doesn't even show up when I search for it on appshopper.com. And even if it did, neither the Mac nor the iPhone app seem to be available outside the US App Store. iTunes and the Mac App Store give me the "change store" message. So no go on this one's out. (I'm in Switzerland, btw).

Can anyone suggest other options? It seems strange to me that there is no definitive answer to a problem that I presume must be a fairly common one.

Comment: [Notificant is no longer in development](http://aayush.me/post/6908650196/and-thats-that). It was my goto app for a while, and I haven't found anything to replace it yet. I've been using The Hit List, but that's more a task manager.

Comment: I ended up going with notifymecloud.com. Works rather well, I must say. If you're looking for an answer to my own question above, I can recommend notifymecloud.com. Reliable and does just what I wanted. Since the iPhone 4S and Siri, however, I don't use it much anymore...

Answer (score 1):

As of OS X Mountain Lion (coming in Summer 2012), [Reminders will have an iCloud-syncing desktop equivalent](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/features.html#reminders).

Since Reminders is integrated with Notifications in iOS, and the desktop edition presumably will work with desktop notifications as well, this should be a good, out-of-the-box way to meet your (simple) stated needs.

Answer (score 0):

The **[Prowl app](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/prowl-growl-client/id320876271?mt=8) (related to Growl)** has an extension **[2Prowl](http://www.prowlapp.com/apps.php)** that does exactly this.

2Prowl sends notifications from Safari on Mac/Windows to the Prowl app on your iPhone.

While 2Prowl is free, Prowl costs little money.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my situation, and it works perfect and it's free!

If you have an iOS 5 device, you can use the '[Reminders](http://www.apple.com/iphone/built-in-apps/reminders.html)' app, build in into the iOS 5. I have MS Outlook installed on both my Mac and (work)PC. If I add a task, reminder, to-do on either of these three devices, iCloud makes sure it's present on all three devices. If I've set an alarm, I get a push notification on my iPhone and a pop-up window on my PC/Mac.
It's fast, it's easy and it's free!

You just need a copy of Outlook (but I guess you can figure something out :))